# Integration of implicit functions

Tags: integration, implicit-function

As we know an implicit function $f(x,y)$ is an expression containing $x$ and $y$ such that none of them can be seperated out.
So my question is how can we integrate or simply find area under an implicit function from $x=a$ to $x=b$ as we cannot seperate $x$ or $y$
Is there some special techniques i would love to know it because it seems to be very difficult as per my knowledge.
I really have a doubt so please give nice answers.

Comment: One way you can do it is parameterizing the function, day you wanted to find the area bound by $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}=1$, you could say $x=\cos^3t$ and $y=\sin^3t$ and evaluate $\int y\,\mathrm{d}x$ with your new parameters. Aside from that there’s not much more I can think of

Comment: but your example is not implicit can we do it for $x^2+xy+y^2=0$

Comment: you could convert to polar with $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ to get $r^2=\frac{1}{1+\sin\theta\cos\theta}$ and try to use standard polar integration techniques

Comment: (i) Expressions are not functions. (ii) Some functions are defined "implicitly" but there's no such thing as an implicit function.

Comment: @ancientmathematician we cannot seperate $x$ or $y$ from $xy=e^{xy}$

Comment: Why does that matter? There are regions where $(x,y)\mapsto e^{xy}-xy$ defines $y$ implicitly as a function of $x$. Let me add (iii) Functions are not expressions.

Comment: @Abhishek. Are you seeking for exact expressions for the integral of functions in implicit form? Or are you looking for a general way of dealing with such cases?

Comment: @DanieleTampieri are exact expression possible? any way is appreciable

Comment: "As we know an implicit function $f(x,y)$ is an expression containing $x$ and $y$ such that none of them can be seperated out." $f(x,y)$ is not the implicit function. And you left some things out. An implicit function is a function defined, locally, by a level set of the form $f(x,y) = c,$ where $c$ is a constant. The implicit function theorem guarantees that this set is locally the graph of a function $y=g(x)$ under certain conditions. It's this function $g$ that is implicitly defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a potential possibility to calculate all implicit derivatives  in the some  points. This allows to build and to integrate Taylor series. And if obtained series converges absolutely, then its sum gives required result.

Answer (score 1):

For a given interval $[a,b]\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, let a function being defined in implicit form by the following equation
$$
f(x,y)=0\quad x\in [a,b]\subseteq\mathbb{R}, y\in\mathbb{R},\tag{1}\label{1}
$$ 
where, obviously, for any given $x\in [a,b]$ *there exist only one* $y$ which satisfies it. To my knowledge, the only general way to integrate a function given in this form is to consider \eqref{1} as the defining equation of a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and measure this set. Precisely, let $$
S_f=\left\{(x,y_o)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x\in D, (y\geq y_o\geq 0\text{ if }y\geq 0)\vee(0> y_0\geq y\text{ if }y<0)\right\}
$$ Then the integral of the function defined by \eqref{1} on $[a,b]$ is given by
$$
\int\limits_{S_f}\!\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
This coincides with the naive definition of the integral of a function as the "*area of the surface under the graph of the function itself*". As implicitly suggested by Teh Rod, by constructing a map $\varphi:D\to S_f$ from a wisely chosen "nice" domain $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ the integral \eqref{2} the following equation can be obtained
$$
\int\limits_{S_f}\!\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int\limits_D\!|J(\varphi)|\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v,\tag{3}\label{3}
$$
where $|J(\varphi)|$ is the [Jacobian determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of the map $\varphi$.
As a final note, since we have $\mathbb{R}^2\equiv\mathbb{C}$, then  $\varphi$ can be chosen to be a [conformal map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map): this, for particular forms of the equation \eqref{1} and thus of $S_f$, can possibly lead to explicitly integrable right sides of equation \eqref{3}.